# Differential entropy / variance

Tags: entropy, information-theory, moments, integral

So I‘m basically more or less trying to prove what is stated in the answer by syeh_106 here:

[Is differential entropy always less than infinity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155939/is-differential-entropy-always-less-than-infinity)

> 1. if the variance is finite, then the differential entropy is also finite.

However, unfortunately I can not find any connection between
$ H(X) = -\int_{S} f(x) ln (f(x)) dx $ and $Var(X)$ (or the moments in general)

> 2)$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x (ln(x))^2} \mathbb{1}_{[e, \infty)(x)} $ (slightly modified from that of the other thread but I also want to show that the differential entropy is infinite)

I have
$H(X) = \int_{e}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{x (ln(x))^2} ln (\frac{1}{x (ln(x))^2} \mathbb{1}_{[e, \infty)(x)}) dx =  \int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x (ln(x))^2} (ln (\frac{1}{x (ln(x))^2}) + ln(\mathbb{1}_{[e, \infty)(x)}))dx  $

Since the indicator function over the integration bounds is 1, the ln would be zero hence

$=  \int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x (ln(x))^2} (ln (\frac{1}{x (ln(x))^2}))dx  $

However from here I do not know how to proceed